# Targetcli can't load modules qla2xxx and ib_srpt

Tags: server, kernel, iscsi

I've installed targetcli from ubuntu repository and when I start targetcli as root, it starts and display following info:

```
Welcome to the targetcli shell:

 Copyright (c) 2011 by RisingTide Systems LLC.

Visit us at http://www.risingtidesystems.com.

Can't load fabric module qla2xxx.
Using iscsi fabric module.
Can't load fabric module ib_srpt.
Using tcm_fc fabric module.
Using loopback fabric module.
/>
```

I've tried modprobe qla2xxx and it doesn't solve the problem.
ib_srpt is not even present in my system, only ib_srp could be found and loading it also didn't solve the problem.

I don't really know what could I do with that.
It's not related to bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/targetcli/+bug/1000490 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs here:

http://www.linux-iscsi.org/wiki/QLogic

It appears you might need to be running with kernel 3.5 for the qla2xxx driver to be in the kernel, Precise Pangolin (12.04 LTS) is using 3.2

I have need to do this very same thing in the near future so I will endeavour to post back once I have the Qlogic hardware and have tried to make it work.

Further to this, I think that ib_srpt / ib_srp are referring to infiniband module/s so might not be a concern unless you were hoping to get LIO working using IB?